# Imprimir dados array PHP

Tags: php

Estou tentando imprimir os dados que tenho no array. Funciona, consigo ver os dados. O meu problema é que quero imprimir esses vários dados dentro da mesma div. Como tenho assim imprime só um valor. E não ponho a div no foreach senão faz outra div.

```
foreach($array_resultados as $key =>$value){
                    //echo "<label><b>".$value['title']."</b></label><br>";
                }
                echo 
                    "<td class='cal_today'><b>

                        <div class =divtoday>
                            <br>".$value['title'] ."
                        </div>
                    </td>";
```

Comment: Você fechou o `foreach` antes de imprimir os valores. E tem uma chave sobrando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes fazer o seguinte código:

```html
$titles = "";
foreach($array_resultados as $key =>$value){
  $titles .= "<label><b>".$value['title']."</b></label><br>";
}
echo  "<td class='cal_today'><b>
          <div class =divtoday>".$titles."</div>
      </td>";
```

Comment: Oi, Daniel, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. É legal explicar, ainda que brevemente, porquê seu código resolve o problema apresentado. Confira [answer] para mais detalhes.

Answer (score 5):

A forma mais prática é armazenar o HTML que o ciclo está a gerar numa variável e após isso fazer uso da variável onde pretendido:

```php
// iniciar variável a vazio
$htmlDoForEach = '';

// por cada entrada na matriz
foreach ($array_resultados as $key => $value) {

    // gerar HTML e adicionar à variável
    $htmlDoForEach.= '
    <div class="divtoday">
        <br>'.$value["title"].'
    </div>';
}

// usar o HTML
echo '<div id="minhaGrandeDiv">'.$htmlDoForEach.'</div>';
```

---

**Nota:** No código da tua pergunta existem algumas coisas incorretas com a *markup* de HTML e com os `}` em PHP que parecem estar a fechar o ciclo do [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) antes de efetivamente estares a fazer uso dos valores na matriz.

Comment: Não fica mais eficiente fazer `echo` do HTML cada iteração do `foreach`?

Comment: Acho que não, também faço assim!

Comment: @JorgeB. Pessoalmente faço: _Recolher dados; Preparar dados; Usar dados._ É o modelo prático que uso à muitos anos e tem-se revelado o mais flexível. Mas em termos de eficiência, penso que "não aquece nem arrefece" num cenário como o presente neste tópico.