# Salvar dados de uma tabela html em array PHP

Tags: php

Possuo uma tabela gerada em html e os dados de cada linha precisam ser salvos em uma tabela no banco de dados. Cada linha representa um item de um carrinho de compra. A estrutura é essa:

```
<table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped" id="tblItens">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 10%">ID</th>
        <th style="width: 36%">Descrição</th>
        <th style="width: 12%">Valor</th>
        <th style="width: 10%">Qtde</th>
        <th style="width: 10%">Desc</th>
        <th style="width: 12%">Total</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Lápis</td>
        <td>2.00</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>10.00</td>
    </tr>
    //e assim por diante...
</tbody>
</table>
```

As `tr` são geradas automaticamente quando um evento é acionado para recolher os dados de outra tabela que existe na página. A função é chamada nesse botão:

```
<i class="fas fa-plus" title="Adicionar" onclick="adicionarItem(this)"></i>
```

Função em javascript:

```
function adicionarItem(e){

    var linha = $(e).closest("tr");

    var nome = linha.find("td:eq(0)").text().trim()
    var precoVenda = linha.find("td:eq(1)").text().trim()
    var id   = linha.find("td:eq(3)").text().trim()
    var precoCusto = linha.find("td:eq(4)").text().trim()

    var table = document.getElementById("tblItens")
    var numOfRows = table.rows.length
    var newRow = table.insertRow(numOfRows)

    newCell = newRow.insertCell(0)
    newCell.innerHTML = ""+ id

    newCell = newRow.insertCell(1)
    newCell.innerHTML = ""+ nome

    newCell = newRow.insertCell(2)
    let inputValor = document.createElement('input')
    inputValor.type = 'text'
    inputValor.id = 'valorProduto'
    inputValor.className = 'form-control form-control-sm'
    inputValor.value = precoVenda
    newCell.appendChild(inputValor)

    newCell = newRow.insertCell(3)
    let inputQtd = document.createElement('input')
    inputQtd.type = 'text'
    inputQtd.id = 'qtdProduto'
    inputQtd.className = 'form-control form-control-sm'
    inputQtd.value = 1
    newCell.appendChild(inputQtd)

    newCell = newRow.insertCell(4)
    let inputDesc = document.createElement('input')
    inputDesc.type = 'text'
    inputDesc.id = 'descProduto'
    inputDesc.className = 'form-control form-control-sm'
    inputDesc.value = 0
    newCell.appendChild(inputDesc)

    newCell = newRow.insertCell(5)
    let inputTotal = document.createElement('input')
    inputTotal.type = 'text'
    inputTotal.id = 'totalProduto'
    inputTotal.className = 'form-control form-control-sm'
    inputTotal.value = precoVenda
    newCell.appendChild(inputTotal)

    newCell = newRow.insertCell(6)
    newCell.className = 'opcoes'
    let inputEdit = document.createElement('i')
    inputEdit.className = 'fas fa-sync-alt'
    inputEdit.title = 'Editar'
    inputEdit.id = 'iEditar'
}
```

Gostaria de saber como posso usar uma função em php para pegar os dados de cada linha e colocá-los em um array. Não tenho ideia de como usar um laço de repetição para isso.

Comment: Isso te ajudaria? Sei que não é o mesmo problema, porém é parecido, acredito eu. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39096/imprimir-dados-array-php?rq=1

Comment: porque você quer fazer isso?

Comment: Preciso pegar esses valores para salvar em uma tabela no banco de dados depois, são os itens de uma respectiva compra.

Comment: Fiz esta pergunta, porque você deve esta fazendo da maneira mais complicada, porque se for só esta página, você pode fazer na mão mesmo que já vai resolver seu problema, porem se for várias paginas, você vai ter mais trabalho para fazer nas outras páginas, executando um script por vez, o que eu queria saber é o porque que você precisa pegar esta informações de uma página html.

Comment: de onde vem os dados da tabela? vc vai fazer na mão?

Comment: Wictor e Lodi, editei a postagem, por favor vejam se dá pra entender melhor agora. E é só nesta página que preciso mesmo Wictor.

Comment: Você pode criar um array na hora que esta adicionando os itens, e quando for enviar, envie este array via ajax para a sua página php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode pegar os dados usando Jquery e os enviar via ajax para a sua página php, o código esta explicando através dos comentários.

```js
var indices = [];

//Pega os indices
$('#tblItens thead tr th').each(function() {
  indices.push($(this).text());
});

var arrayItens = [];

//Pecorre todos os produtos
$('#tblItens tbody tr').each(function( index ) {

  var obj = {};
  
  //Controle o objeto
  $(this).find('td').each(function( index ) {
    obj[indices[index]] = $(this).text();
  });
  
  //Adiciona no arrray de objetos
  arrayItens.push(obj);
  
});

//Mostra dados pegos no console
console.log(arrayItens);

//Envia para o php
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "suapagina.php",
  data: arrayItens,
  success: function(respostaDoPhp){
    alert('Deu tudo certo');
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped" id="tblItens">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 10%">ID</th>
        <th style="width: 36%">Descrição</th>
        <th style="width: 12%">Valor</th>
        <th style="width: 10%">Qtde</th>
        <th style="width: 10%">Desc</th>
        <th style="width: 12%">Total</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Lápis</td>
        <td>2.00</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>10.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Lápis1</td>
        <td>2.00</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>10.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Lápis2</td>
        <td>2.00</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>10.00</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Wictor, o problema é que na página existe mais de uma tabela, como faço para identificá-la pelo id ?

Comment: Sim, você pode usar o id da table, vou editar a minha resposta, utilizando o id da table

Comment: Pronto, editei usando o id da table, simplesmente coloquei "#tblItens", que é o id relativo a aquela table.

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou corretamente. Última dúvida, vi que você usou o "$(this).text();" para pegar o texto dentro das <td> e, no meu caso que tenho um <input>, o que eu deveria fazer ?

Comment: para pegar dos inputs é só colocar $(this).val(), quando você usa o val você pega o value do input

Comment: Tentei substituir pelo val() ele não pega os valores, deixa como vazio. Tenho que definir alguma condição ?

Comment: faço o seguinte aqui, faço um foreach $(this).find('td').each( pegando todos os td, ou seja quando faço a referencia do "$(this)", estou referenciando os "td", se o seu input esta dentro do  "td", vou tem que fazer $(this).find('input').val(), ou seja, ele seleciona o td e depois o input e depois pega o valor do input